AWS API Gateway problem when connecting it to my upload button
I was trying to make an app using AWS and react to upload files and I didn't have any problems until I tried to click on the upload button which gave me an error telling me there's a problem with the post in the API.
When I click the upload button it gave me these errors:
net::ERR_FAILED 403 (Forbidden)

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://6w6k152g.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev1/test from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

There was an error uploading the file! Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:84:1)

Here is the part of the code that caused the problem:
 axios.post("https://6w152g.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev1/test", formData)
      .then(response => {
        console.log('File uploaded successfully:', response.data);
        this.setState({
          SelectedFile: null,
          fileUploadedSuccessfully: true,
          noFileSelectedWarning: false,
          errorMessage: ''
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('There was an error uploading the file!', error);
        this.setState({
          errorMessage: 'There was an error uploading the file.'
        });
      });
  };

I remake the API from the start using How to Build a File Upload System on AWS with React and a Serverless API | Lambda, S3, API Gateway - YouTube.

Looks like a CORS error.  Add http://localhost:3000 to the list of allowed origins.

Where are you trying to place the uploaded file?

You should enable CORS in your React API and try it again. Additionally, you can add a proxy in your web app since it runs locally.
Ensure the API is publicly available.
